# VBNET How to pause printer queue?

Tags: vb.net, printers

Can I use a button to pause and release printer queue? I mean just pause the data to printer from my PC.

Comment: [Win32_PrintJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-printjob). See the `Pause` and `Resume` methods. If the current Job has already been buffered (by the printer), you cannot pause it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But do I need a timer to pause every job? Can I pause the queue, and it can't print everytime until I release it?

Answer (score 1):

.NET provides [PrintQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printqueue) class from `System.Printing`.

This class supports methods such as [Pause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printqueue.pause), [Resume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printqueue.resume), [Purge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printqueue.purge) methods to control the print queue.

Comment: I'm a new vbneter. These articles are a bit difficult for me. Anyway, thank you for your help.